# P value for bootstrapping two means in laymen's terms

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, bootstrap

I've bootstrapped two means - 
each sample had 10,000 observations so I resampled each mean with replacement of 10,000 numbers from each sample.

I did this over 50,000 iterations

I've plotted the distributions of the bootstrapped means and it looks like they are different. However I'm lost in the next step.

Is someone able to tell me in laymen's terms how I can calculate a P value and how to know if one bootstrapped distribution is significantly different from the other?

I am using R to do my bootstrapping.

Comment: Can you provide your  code?

Comment: This questions appears answer your question: [Bootstrap, distribution of H0 and comparison of two means: replacement within the groups or within the pooled sample](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136661/bootstrap-distribution-of-h0-and-comparison-of-two-means-replacement-within-th?newreg=593eaa14d4764258b263e1c2c1383b72)